# Mezzanine COMMENTS_APP customisation failing

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I'm using Mezzanine to help build a project i'm working on at the moment, and i'm having a problem making COMMENTS_APP work. I've made my custom app an INSTALLED_APP, and denoted that it was the COMMENTS_APP, put this

```
from modify.models import CustomComment 
from modify.forms import CustomCommentForm

def get_model():
     return CustomComment 
def get_form():
     return CustomCommentForm
```

In the **init**.py of the app. I've put

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import class_prepared
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from mezzanine.core.fields import FileField, RichTextField
from mezzanine.core.models import RichText, Orderable, Slugged
from mezzanine.core.models import SiteRelated
from mezzanine.pages.models import Page
from mezzanine.blog.models import BlogPost
from mezzanine.utils.models import upload_to
from django_comments.models import Comment

    class CustomComment(Comment):
         pass
```

as my model, and i still have this error, and for the life of me, i can't work out how to fix it. What am i am missing? What's causing this error? This is the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 28, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/ashleyg/DisabilityProject/disproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "/home/ashleyg/DisabilityProject/disproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
django.setup()
  File "/home/ashleyg/DisabilityProject/disproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/ashleyg/DisabilityProject/disproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/ashleyg/DisabilityProject/disproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 87, in create
module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
  File "/home/ashleyg/DisabilityProject/rating/modify/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from modify.models import CustomComment
  File "/home/ashleyg/DisabilityProject/rating/modify/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from mezzanine.core.models import RichText, Orderable, Slugged
  File "/home/ashleyg/DisabilityProject/disproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/core/models.py", line 24, in <module>
from mezzanine.core.managers import DisplayableManager, CurrentSiteManager
  File "/home/ashleyg/DisabilityProject/disproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/core/managers.py", line 16, in <module>
    from mezzanine.conf import settings
  File "/home/ashleyg/DisabilityProject/disproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/conf/__init__.py", line 202, in <module>
module = import_module(app)
  File "/home/ashleyg/DisabilityProject/disproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 46, in import_module
__import__(name)
 ImportError: No module named CustomComment
```

This is my pip freeze

```
Django==1.7.6
Mezzanine==3.1.10
Pillow==2.7.0
South==1.0.2
argparse==1.2.1
beautifulsoup4==4.1.3
bleach==1.4.1
django-autocomplete-light==2.0.9
django-choices==1.3
filebrowser-safe==0.3.8
future==0.9.0
grappelli-safe==0.3.13
html5lib==0.999
oauthlib==0.7.2
postgres==2.1.2
psycopg2==2.6
python-debian==0.1.23
pytz==2014.10
requests==2.6.0
requests-oauthlib==0.4.2
six==1.9.0
tzlocal==1.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
```